# Python imports fail when using unittest module

Tags: python, python-import, python-unittest

I have the following directory structure:

```
project/
    lambda_functions/
        user_plot
            user_plot_lib/
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── a.py
            └── b.py
            user_plot_client.py
          
    test/
        unit/
           ├── __init__.py
           ├── test_user_plot.py
```

Inside of my `user_plot_client.py` I have imports like so:

```py
from user_plot_lib.a import test_function
```

I can successfully run code from the `user_plot_client.py` .

In `test_user_plot.py` I have the following

```py
from lambda_functions.user_plot.user_plot_client import main

class TestUserPlot(unittest.Testcase):
  def test_main():
      pass
```

I get the following import error

```
from user_plot_lib.a import test_function 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named user_plot_lib
```

I know it's something to do with the Python path, but I'm not having any luck getting it added. Any better way to structure this so that I don't have to mess with the python path?

Comment: How do you execute the code?

Comment: It looks like you could use `from .user_plot_lib.a import test_function` in `user_plot_client.py`, if `user_plot_client.py` is imported as a module.

Comment: In order for the absolute import to work, the necessary folder needs to be on the `sys.path`. Please see the linked duplicate to understand how it's initialized; or you can add it manually (not recommended). The short version is: you can run the test code starting from the correct folder; or you can install the package you want to test (of course, if `user_plot` rather than `lambda_functions` is the intended top-level package for distribution, then that's where the path should start for the relative import).